# rails 4: response to ajax post results in error for rendering response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

In my rails 4 project, I submit data with a POST and jquery like this (watch out, coffee-script):

```
post_data =
        site_id: site
        url: '//' + $('#host-holder').data('host') + '/' + key

$.post("/sites/" + site + "/images",post_data, (success) ->
        #successful_post
 ).fail( (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        #post failed
 )
```

In my controller, if I do:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render nothing: true}
end
```

the POST submit works fine (success callback in ajax client runs), but if I do this:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render json: @image.to_json, status: :created}
end
```

it fails (fail callback in ajax client runs).

Why that? What am I doing wrong in responding to the ajax request?
(Note: no error reported server-side)

EDIT: The error is "`parsererror`", I actually have the whole object there! It says `"missing ; before statement"`...and this is the response object: `"{"id":24,"url":"<EDITED FOR SECURITY>","thumbnail":null,"status":null,"site_id":28,"created_at":"2014-10-05T02:53:50.030Z","updated_at":"2014-10-05T02:53:50.030Z","quality":"good"}"`

Comment: What is the fail description in the console?

Comment: @ControlFreak please see my EDIT; I would suppose that `@image.to_json` in my controller would construct correct json?

Comment: You can check if your json is correct by using a json validator like jsonlint.  Are you setting the `content-type` header to `application/json` in your response?

Comment: @ControlFreak I think the problem was not in the response, but in the request: I was using the jquery.post() shorthand, which may have been setting the data type wrong :)

Comment: I see, then you can use `$.get()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here Your ajax statement should like this,

```
$.ajax({
  URL: '/controller_name/action_name',           // url must be proper
  type: 'POST',
  data: { username: 'test' },
  success: function(response){
    alert(response);
  },
})
```

In Route.rb:

```
post '/action_name' => 'controller_name#action_name'
```

In Controller file:

```
def action_name
  @username = params[:username]
  data = {:message => "Alert this!"}
  render :json => data
end
```